# MongoDB $or / $and command optimisations

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm trying to figure out why the below MongoDB aggregate query takes so long, when there's 18 `$or` conditions.

I'm able to remove **any one** of the conditions (making it 17), and the query is completed in less than 100ms, however with 18 it jumps up to ~20 seconds.

I could understand if there was a specific condition causing an issue, however I can't get my head around why I can remove any of them and the response time drops down to ~100ms.

I've also checked memory useage while this commands running and it only takes up about 15% of the boxes total memory. From my understanding there's no specified memory limit to MongoDB?

Also, the query brings back the expected result.

Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

```
db.getCollection('messages').aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":8},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":64},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":9},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":77},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":76},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":6},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":62},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":63},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":84},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":99},{"created_date":{"$gt":1436793531100}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":1},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":93},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":148},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":114},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":145},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":174},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":175},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]},
                    {"$and":[{"channel_id":146},{"created_date":{"$gt":0}}]}
                    ]
                }
        },
        {
            $group: { _id : '$channel_id', count: { $sum: 1 }}
        }
    ]);
```

**Edit 1:**

I've tried removing the redundant `$and` statements as Sammaye pointed out, with the same results.

I've also noticed that I can add a 19th `$or` condition and it returns in under 100ms.

Also I'm on version 2.6.7 of MongoDB.

I have indexes on both the `channel_id` and `created_date` fields.

I tried to add the `explain` option to the aggregate command, as Ishamael suggested, however it doesn't seem to have any effect on the output. Also adding `.hint( { channel_id: 1 } )` or `.hint( { created_date: 1 } )` onto the end of the query doesn't seem to work and I end up with a TypeError.

Here's the updated query - with `explain` turned on:

```
db.getCollection('messages').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {"channel_id":8, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":64, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":9, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":77, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":76, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":6, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":62, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":63, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":84, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":99, "created_date":{"$gt":1436793531100}},
                {"channel_id":1, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":93, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":148, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":114, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":145, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":174, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":175, "created_date":{"$gt":0}},
                {"channel_id":146, "created_date":{"$gt":0}}
                ]
            }
    },
    {
        $group: { _id : '$channel_id', count: { $sum: 1 }}
    }
], { explain: true });
```

And the result:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : 175,
        "count" : 4.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 146,
        "count" : 1.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 145,
        "count" : 3.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 8,
        "count" : 17.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 148,
        "count" : 1.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 84,
        "count" : 16.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "count" : 5067.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 76,
        "count" : 15.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 77,
        "count" : 2.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 174,
        "count" : 8.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 64,
        "count" : 2.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 93,
        "count" : 7.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 6,
        "count" : 93.0000000000000000
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 114,
        "count" : 6.0000000000000000
    }
],
"ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Comment: Can you paste `explain` output for query with 17 indexes and 18 indexes? I suspect that mongodb has a limit on how many index seeks it will do, and when you have 18 clauses, it switches to table scan, making a wrong assumption that it would be faster.

Comment: Also, what happens if you append `.hint( { channel_id: 1 } )` at the end of your query? Or `.hint( { created_date: 1 } )`, depending on which one you have an index on.

Comment: The $and is redundant and could be causing problems with your index, remove it

Comment: Can you also tell us the MongoDB version since $or mechanics have changed between versions?

Comment: As for the arbitrary number of $or clauses... Hmm, I am uncertain sounds really odd to me, however, on previus versions of MongoDB I can imagine the $or having a predetermined limit like that which wold cause stacking of $or clause queries.

Comment: I've tried some of your suggestions, check out the edited question - sadly no luck so far, but thanks for helping out!

Comment: Grr I cannot seem to find the JIRA now for when $or was converted to basically an $in behind the scenes. I cannot be sure if it was 2.6 or 3.0. Is it easy for you upgrade and quickly test with a new MongoDB binary?

Comment: So hang on, it is specifically with 18, any more or less and it works?

Comment: @Sammaye, Yep, so far it only seems to be an issue with 18 conditions - I'll upgrade to the latest version, do some more debugging and report back tomorrow as it's midnight here in the UK.

Comment: Np, I am UK time too. Maybe an upgrade will sort it, if not this sounds way too specific to not be a bug

Comment: So, I've managed to upgrade to version 3.0.4 and the problem has disappeared! Must have been some strange bug in 2.6.7. Thanks for the help and suggestions guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not 100% sure if this is a bug in 2.6.7 but upgrading to the latest version (3.0.4 at time of posting) seemed to fix my problems.